# Flipping or rotating a one dimensional array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, math

I have a one dimensional array which represents a two dimensional grid. The number of rows and columns are known. It is read from the 'top left' to 'bottom right' so the first item will be R1C1 and the last item will RXCY (where X = row number and Y = col number;

My goal is to 'flip' or 'rotate' the two-d array and return a new one-d array representing the transformation.

I tried bitwise manipulation but couldn't get it to work with the fact that the row/col counts could be either odd or even. I also tried an iterative approach but got lost in the logic weeds.

A minimal javascript example: a 3^3 grid of booleans in a 9 item array and placeholders for the three functions I'm struggling with:

```js
let startingArray = 
                [true,  false, false,
                 true,  true,  true,
                 false, false, false];
let rows = 3;
let cols = 3;


function flipVertical(arrayToFlip){
  
  //Logic to replace here
  let flippedArray = arrayToFlip;

  return flippedArray;  
}

function flipHorizontal(arrayToFlip){
  
  //Logic to replace here
  let flippedArray = arrayToFlip;

  return flippedArray;  
}

function rotate90Clockwise(arrayToRotate){
  
  //Logic to replace here
  let rotatedArray = arrayToRotate;

  return rotatedArray ;  
}


console.log(flipVertical(startingArray));
// should return 
//  false, false, false, 
//  true, true, true, 
//  true, false, false

console.log(flipHorizontal(startingArray));
// should return 
// false, false, true, 
// true, true, true, 
// false, false, false

console.log(rotate90Clockwise(startingArray));
// should return 
//false, true, true, 
//false, true, false, 
//false, true, false
```

Comment: Should it be done in-place ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a basic iteration, you can loop through rows and, within each row, loop through cols.

The key part is:

```
arr[r * cols + c]
```

Start with a "duplicate" function that simply loops through the number or rows and the number cols from

```
let rows = 3;
let cols = 3;
```

and pushes to a new array

```
    function duplicate(arr) {
      var result = [];
      for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
          result.push(arr[r * cols + c]);
        }
      }
      return result;
    }
```

you can then manipulate this basic iteration to reverse rows (flipVertical):

```
for (var r = rows - 1; r >= 0; r--) {
```

or reverse columns (flipHorizontal)

```
  for (var c = cols - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
```

to rotate, you switch the `r * cols + c` to `c * rows + r` depending on which way you want to rotate

Giving:

```js
let startingArray = [true, false, false,
  true, true, true,
  false, false, false
];
let rows = 3;
let cols = 3;

console.log(startingArray);
console.log(duplicate(startingArray));
console.log(flipVertical(startingArray));
console.log(flipHorizontal(startingArray));
console.log(rotate90Clockwise(startingArray));

function duplicate(arr) {
  var result = [];
  for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
      result.push(arr[r * cols + c]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

function flipVertical(arr) {
  var result = [];
  for (var r = rows - 1; r >= 0; r--) {
    for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
      result.push(arr[r * cols + c]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

function flipHorizontal(arr) {
  var result = [];
  for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    for (var c = cols - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
      result.push(arr[r * cols + c]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

function rotate90Clockwise(arr) {
  var result = [];
  for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    for (var c = cols - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
      result.push(arr[c * rows + r]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for `flipVertical`.
Basically I created 2 function to map array index to col/row and back.
I also created a function to transform an array using a function that map one index to another.

So in order to create `flipVertical` I wrote the logic like this:

- map original index to col/row
- compute new row (and col if necessary)
- map new row/col to new index

For there I think you can write the other functions :)

```js
let startingArray = 
                [true,  false, false,
                 true,  true,  true,
                 false, false, false];
let rows = 3;
let cols = 3;

function transformArray(originalArray, indexMapFn) {
  const resultArray = originalArray.concat();
  for (let i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++) {
    resultArray[i] = originalArray[indexMapFn(i)];
  }
  return resultArray;
}

function mapIndexToColRow(i) {
  const row = Math.floor(i / cols);
  const col = i % cols;
  return { row, col };
}

function mapColRowToIndex(col, row) {
  return row * cols + col;
}

function flipVertical(arrayToFlip){
  return transformArray(arrayToFlip, (i) => {
    const { row, col } = mapIndexToColRow(i);
    const pivotRow = (rows-1)/2;
    const distToPivot = pivotRow - row;
    const newRow = pivotRow + distToPivot;
    // once you get the logic you can simplify to:
    // newRow = (rows - 1) - row
    return mapColRowToIndex(col, newRow);
  });
}

console.log(flipVertical(startingArray));
// should return 
//  false, false, false, 
//  true, true, true, 
//  true, false, false
```

Answer (score 0):

With a simple `transpose` helper, which flips a matrix across its main diagonal we can write really simple versions of `flipHorizontal` and `rotate90Clockwise`, etc:

```js
const flipHorizontal = (xs) => xs .map (x => [...x] .reverse())
const flipVertical = (xs) => [...xs] .reverse()
const rotate90Clockwise = (xs) => transpose ([...xs] .reverse())
const rotate90Counter = (xs) => transpose (xs) . reverse ()
```

And if we reify `map` and `reverse` into pure functions, and add `compose`, they could be even simpler:

```js
const flipHorizontal = map (reverse)
const flipVertical = reverse
const rotate90Clockwise = compose (transpose, reverse)
const rotate90Counter = compose (reverse, transpose)
```

But these functions operate on two-dimensional arrays (technically arrays of arrays in JS.)  We need functions that operate on a one-dimensional array, as though it were a two-dimensional array with each row being `cols` entries long.  We could rewrite our simple functions, and it wouldn't be too difficult.  But we could also *wrap* them in other functions.  If we had a `nest` function which took the number of columns desired and turned it into that two-dimensional grid, we could call `nest` first, then run, say, `flipHorizontal` and then used `Array.prototype.flat` to return them to the flattened form.  This would mean that our simple functions would stay simple, and we could still use them directly when needed.

A `nest` function is also pretty simple, and with the helpers we've already discussed, we could build `fromFlat`, which takes the number of columns and a function and gives you backed a wrapped version of one these matrix manipulation functions so that it starts and end with a flat array, but converts it to a matrix before applying the manipulation and back to a flat array afterward.

It could look like this:

```js
const reverse = (xs) => [...xs] .reverse();
const transpose = (xs) => xs [0] .map ((_, i) => xs .map (r => r[i]))
const flatten = (xss) =>  xss .flat ()
const map = (fn) => (o) => Array .isArray (o) 
  ? o .map (x => fn (x)) 
  : Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (o) .map (([k, v]) => [k, fn (v)]))
const compose = (...fns) => (x) => [...fns] .reduceRight ((a, fn) => fn (a), x)

const nest = (c) => (xs) =>
  xs .length < c ? [...xs] : [xs .slice (0, c), ...nest (c) (xs .slice (c))]

const fromFlat = (cols) => (fn) => compose (flatten, fn, nest (cols))

const flipHor = map (reverse)
const flipVert =  reverse
const rotateCW = compose (transpose, reverse)
const rotateCCW = compose (reverse, transpose)

const cols = 3

const flipHorizontal = fromFlat (cols) (flipHor)
const flipVertical = fromFlat (cols) (flipVert)
const rotate90Clockwise = fromFlat (cols) (rotateCW)
const rotate90Counter = fromFlat (cols) (rotateCCW)

const display = (c) => (name) => (xs) => console .log (`${name}:\n${name.replace(/./g, '=')}=\n${nest (c) (xs) .map (xs => xs .map (x => String (x) .padEnd (5, ' ')) .join (' ')) .join ('\n')}\n\n`)

const startingArray = [true,  false, false, true,  true,  true, false, false, false]

display (cols) ('original') (startingArray)
display (cols) ('flipHorizontal') (flipHorizontal (startingArray))
display (cols) ('flipVertical') (flipVertical (startingArray))
display (cols) ('rotate90Clockwise') (rotate90Clockwise (startingArray))
display (cols) ('rotate90Counter') (rotate90Counter (startingArray))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Note that all functions are quite simple, except for `map`, which is designed to handle either arrays (`map ((n) => n * n) ([1, 2, 3]) //=> [1, 4, 9]`) or on objects (`map ((n) => n * n) ({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}) //=> {a: 1, b: 4, c: 9}`.)  And this one isn't too bad.

And we've successfully decomposed our problem into reusable functions.